# Warning to check permission still shown if checkSelfPermission() extracted to a method

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

I get why Android Studio shows the `MissingPermission` warning.

> Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with checkPermission) or explicitly handle a potential SecurityException less... (⌘F1)

If there is an `@RequiresPermission` annotated method, the permission needs to be checked. So to prevent the warning, I need to do:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.PERMISSION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    methodThatNeedsAPermission();
}
```

Now, this is quite a long code to have in a condition check. Moreover, I want my code to be clean, I want to extract the check to keep business logic and UI / Context-related Android code separated, so I'd like to have:

```
public void startDoingSomething() {
    if (hasPermission()) {
        methodThatNeedsAPermission();
    }
}

...

public boolean hasPermission() {
    return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.PERMISSION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
```

But with this, Android Studio still shows the warning.

Of course, I could suppress the warning with `@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")` but why should I? **I am checking for the permission.**

Is there a clean way to get around this? Some kind of annotation I'd add to `hasPermission()` method so that Android Studio knows that I am checking for the permission?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm wondering the same thing 3 years later.

Comment: No, I haven't, sadly. Seems to be a problem with Android lint.

Comment: I thought that too. I started handling the SecurityException rather than checking for permission. I have to handle different permissions in different Android versions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation like this and the solution was to follow this path

File > Settings > Editor > inspections > Android click down pointer
Lint click down pointer > Correctness click down pointer
then under Messages scroll down to Missing Permissions un-check the box
Click Apply and OK

Lint is great but not always correct

Comment: Well, I would rather not disable the check for all my projects. Moreover, everybody working with the code base would still be getting that warning.