# Check self permission not working correctly in Android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions

I want to `checkSelfPermission` in multiple places in my same file. I tried to make a function and check the condition, but it still complains the error.

```
fun checkPermissionTwo(): Boolean {
    return permissionsCheck().all { permission ->
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            application.applicationContext, permission
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }
}

internal fun permissionsCheck(): List<String> {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        listOf(
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        )
    } else {
        listOf(
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        )
    }
}
```

I am trying to check `checkPermissionTwo()` in where errors

```
fun stopScan(adapter: BluetoothAdapter) {
    if (isBluetoothStateOn(adapter), checkPermissionTwo()) {
        bluetoothLeScanner?.stopScan(leScanCallback)
    }
}
```

**Image**

[image]

**Error**

```
Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with checkPermission) or explicitly handle a potential SecurityException
```

Comment: `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` can raise SecurityException which you need to handle either by `try/catch` or by `checkPermission`

Comment: what do you mean that?

Comment: Bluetooth scan needs access fine location maybe on new device.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a limitation on Android Studio, you need to directly wrap your function call with the corresponding permission.

```kotlin
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    bluetoothLeScanner?.stopScan(leScanCallback)
}
```

For details you may refer to [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52314830/warning-to-check-permission-still-shown-if-checkselfpermission-extracted-to-a).

Comment: Yes but don't use those nullable values to call b=adapter if b!=null b.isenabled.  b.stopdiscovery b.blah...